# Use a fixed view to all my Activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I want a view much like menubar at the bottom of the screen.
I want to keep it in all the activity i have.

Is there any way to keep this view in all the activity without copy & pasting it to all the activity?

If you know about it let me know ASAP.

---

Shaiful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to define the common view in a separate layout file, and include it at the end of each layout using the include tag.

More about it here, http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout for the button bar and reuse/include it using .
[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) should help.